# Connection string for SAS token in Azure event hub python

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-eventhub, azure-sas

I am pretty new to event hub

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/get-started-python-send-v2

based on the above link I am trying to implement a publisher for event hub.
Unfortunately the connection string is formed with Shared Access Key and not SAS (Shared Access Signature) as shown below

Endpoint=sb:///;SharedAccessKeyName=;SharedAccessKey=

I am unable to find a source that uses SAS token instead of the key.
Is this supported in the library or is there any other way to achieve this

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no support for SharedAccessSignature token. At the moment, this feature is discussed at https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk/issues/1701#issuecomment-675855269

Comment: I'd chime in that we have a sample we've been passing around when folks requested this behavior, to allow users to produce and consume SAS tokens through the credential flow.  Kindly see the example here https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/azure-eventhub/samples/sync_samples/authenticate_with_sas_token.py and don't hesitate to give us a shout in the repo if there are any issues.